# iOS error "Initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *')

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to get the time interval between two NSDates, namely `previousActivity.stopTime`and `previousActivity.startTime`. I'm getting an error with this code:

```
NSTimeInterval *previousActivityDuration = [previousActivity.stopTime timeIntervalSinceDate:previousActivity.startTime];
```

Here's the error message:

`"Initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')"`

I don't get it; If NSTimeInterval is aka 'double', how is the initialization expression incompatible, and how do I fix it?

Many thanks!

**Edit:**

Per @Rmaddy's comment, I removed the asterisk. Then I get this error in the line immediately following:

`Assigning to 'NSNumber *' from incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')`

Here's the offending line:

```
previousActivity.duration = previousActivityDuration;
```

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a primitive type. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: The error message no doubt is `Initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')`, but the `*` got lost because the message was not properly quoted as "code".

Comment: That second error is because you can't simply assign from double to `NSNumber*`.

Comment: Change the new line to `previousActivity.duration = @(previousActivityDuration);`.

Comment: @Hot--Can you please show code to correct?

Comment: That fixed it, @rmaddy! I obviously need to understand this better, and will research the underlying error in my thinking. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to learn the difference between "objects" and primitive/scalar values.

Comment: Indeed I do, @Hot. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attempting to make an `NSTimeInterval` pointer variable, but what you really want is just an `NSTimeInterval` variable. So remove the asterisk like this:

```
NSTimeInterval previousActivityDuration = [previousActivity.stopTime timeIntervalSinceDate:previousActivity.startTime];
```

Your code was complaining because the types were different. Usually we only use pointers for Objective-C objects, and only where necessary do we generally use pointers for primitive types such as `double`s and such.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the error carefully, you can understand that you need to change

```
NSTimeInterval *previousActivityDuration
```

to

```
NSTimeInterval previousActivityDuration
```

(remove the asterisk)

If you cmd+click `NSTimeInterval` you will see this line:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

meaning that it's just a primitive, not a class.